# Does Java Have the Equivalent of Python's "string.ascii_uppercase"?

Tags: java

Python's string module has a few handy operations that will return a certain character sets, such as all the uppercase characters.  Is there anything similar for Java?

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

```
string.ascii_lowercase
```

The lowercase letters 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.

```
string.ascii_uppercase
```

The uppercase letters 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.

```
string.digits
```

The string '0123456789'.

```
string.punctuation
```

String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters in the C locale.

Comment: Why are you trying to do with this? Why not just check if a character is within a value range?

Comment: You could simply create your own String Utility class with some `static String` like `public final static String UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`

Comment: The abswer is no, but I've never needed it, because you can use regex to match characters, or if you need the letter's index, you can use arithmetic: `char c = 'd'; int index = c - 'a'; // 3`

Comment: For punctuation: http://ideone.com/QpuU16 should be everything in unicode :)

Answer (score 3):

No.  You'd need to write a loop:

```
String result = "";
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
  result += c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed.  And that's why one should always run code and not just type it into a browser :).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do toLowerCase() and toUpperCase()

```
String abc = aBc;
abc.toLowerCase(); // abc
abc.toUpperCase(); // ABC
```

EDIT: I misread the OP.
OP doesn't want to convert strings, but get a collections of all Upper-/Lowercases, Punctiation and Numbers, using Java

```
public static char[] getUpper() {
    char[] res = new char[26];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {
        res[i] = 'A' + i;
    }
    return res;
}

// Or just do getUpper().toLowerCase();
public static char[] getUpper() {
    char[] res = new char[26];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {
        res[i] = 'a' + i;
    }
    return res;
}

public static char[] getUpper() {
    char[] res = new char[10];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        res[i] = '0' + i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

For punctuations I really don't know

You can ofc just use some directly returning methods, as you know what the output should be.

```
public static String getUpper() {
    return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
}

public static String getLower() {
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}

public static String getDigits() {
    return "0123456789"
}

public static String getPunctuation() {
    return ".," // Don't really know what this should return
}
```

Comment: OP is looking for something that would return something like "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" rather than turn the input to uppercase.

Comment: Using `somestring += i` is extremely wasteful when it comes to objects and memory. A [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) would be in order. Consider using new StringBuilder(26) -- after all, you do know how big that string will be.

Comment: Memory is barely an issue nowadays, definitly for such a simple method

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own,

UPPERCASE

```
public String uppercase()
{
    String answer = "";
    char c;
    for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) 
    {
        answer += c;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

LOWERCASE

```
public String lowercase()
{
    String answer = "";
    char c;
    for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) 
    {
        answer += c;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

NUMBERS

```
public String numbers()
{
    String answer = "";
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<9;i++) 
    {
        answer += i;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Probably should use StringBuffer and append instead of concatenation

Comment: The `answer += c` is *extremely* wasteful when it comes to objects and memory.  A [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) would be in order.  Consider using `new StringBuilder(26)` -- after all, you do know how big that string will be.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simple answer is that there is no direct equivalent.

Obviously, if you simply want all of the uppercase letters in (say) ASCII, then it is a trivial task to implement.  Java doesn't implement it in a standard API.  I imagine that's because:

- it is trivial to implement yourself,
- they do not want APIs that mix up the distinction between encoded and decoded characters, and
- they do not want to encourage code that hard-wires use of specific character sets / encodings.

Java's internal character representation is Unicode based.  Unicode is essentially a catalog of character code points from many languages and writing systems.  There is a subsystem for mapping between Java's internal Unicode-based text representation an external character encodings such as ASCII, LATIN-1 ... and UTF-8.  Some of these support all Unicode code points, and others don't.

So if you wanted a *general* solution to the problem of "find me all uppercase letters in some character set XYX", you'd need to do something like this:

1. Obtain the Java `Charset` object for "XYZ".
2. Enumerate all of the *valid* characters in the character set "XYZ".
3. Obtain the `CharsetDecoder` object for the character set, and use it to decode each valid character ... to a Unicode code point.
4. Use the Java `Character` class to test the code point's Unicode attributes; e.g. whether it is a "letter", whether it is "upper case" and so on.  (Use [`Character.getType(codepoint)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType%28int%29))

I imagine this procedure (or similar) is implementable, but I'm not aware of any standard Java APIs or 3rd party Java APIs that do that.

Answer (score -3):

try this method toUpperCase().

Comment: It appears that the OP is looking for a string constant of `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` - not the way to convert a string to upper case.